# how to display image from static django folder in vue using v-html

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a png image in static folder of my Django app which works fine when called from html file as below:

```
<img src="{% static 'app1/emojis/celebration.png' %}">
```

But when i have

```
img_name:"<img src=\"{% static \'app1/emojis/celebration.png\' %}\" alt=\"img_error\" >"
```

in javascript file and I render it in html as `<span v-html="img_name">  </span>`
the image is not shown. instead the alternate text `"img_error"` is shown.

A normal html tag without any static file is rendered correctly:

in Javascript:

```
h_tag:"<h1> hello </h1>"
```

in Html:

```
<span v-html="h_tag">  </span>
```

So how can i make Vue understand the folder path to static files in Django.
I am not asking how to change delimiters for Vue when using with Django.

Comment: Not familiar with v-html but the static tag most likely doesn't know what to do with the '\' before the quotes to your image.

Comment: I tried without '\' too. it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines of code below work exactly the same way in Django:
The second method works for Vue too. so its convenient to use the second method.

```
<img src="{% static 'app1/emojis/celebration.png' %}">
<img src="/static/app1/emojis/celebration.png" >
```